# Why can't I install the css-lightbox compass plugin with gem install

Tags: rubygems, sass, compass-sass

I am trying to install a compass plugin for css lightboxes [compass-css-lightbox](https://github.com/ericam/compass-css-lightbox/blob/master/README.mkdn) but I am running into issues with gem install.

```
$sudo gem install css-lightbox

Fetching: css-lightbox-0.2.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed css-lightbox-0.2.0
Installing ri documentation for css-lightbox-0.2.0
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rdoc/rdoc.rb:280: warning: conflicting chdir during another chdir block
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rdoc/rdoc.rb:287: warning: conflicting chdir during another chdir block
Done installing documentation for css-lightbox after 0 seconds
1 gem installed

compass install css-lightbox
No such framework: "css-lightbox"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have added `require 'css-lightbox'` to your Compass configuration file, e. g. `config.rb`.

Comment: OK!  The document error was just a red herring then.  Thanks.